# WPF Data Binding From UserControl

Tags: wpf, binding, wpf-controls, tabcontrol, wpf-4.0

I want to bind 'SomeText' from my UserControl, into the Content of my Label.

I currently have a UserControl which just displays my 'SomeText'. The XAML, and Code Behind file can be seen below.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TabHeader.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="183" d:DesignWidth="235"
             x:Name="uc">
    <Grid>
        <Label Height="43" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,102,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Content="{Binding Path=SomeText, ElementName=uc}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="86" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>


namespace TabHeader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        private string someText;

        public UserControl1()
        {
            this.SomeText = "23";

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string SomeText
        {
            get 
            { 
                return someText; 
            }
            set
            {
                someText = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then have my main XAML page where I have, a Tab Control within a Grid. I'm using a Style to generate two Labels within the Columns Header. I am able to pull through the Header field, but I am unable to pull through the controls field.

```
<Window x:Class="TabHeader.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:TabHeader"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="Tabs">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Height="262" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,26,0,0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="366">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="tabItemHeaderStyle" >
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" >
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem}}"/>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=SomeText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=vw:UserControl1}}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>

            </TabControl.Resources>

            <TabItem Style="{StaticResource tabItemHeaderStyle}" Header="TI 1" Name="tabItem1" Width="100">
                <vw:UserControl1 x:Name="UserControl11"></vw:UserControl1>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Style="{StaticResource tabItemHeaderStyle}" Header="TI 2" Name="tabItem2">
            </TabItem>

        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

**Edit 1**
For anyone interested added my working code below, where I have used the DependencyProperty.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
<TabControl Height="262" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,26,0,0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="366">
    <TabControl.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="tab1ItemHeaderStyle">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem}}"/>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=UC1Figure, ElementName=uc1}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>

    <TabItem Style="{StaticResource tab1ItemHeaderStyle}" Header="[Tab 1]" Name="tabItem1" Width="100">
        <vw:UserControl1 x:Name="uc1"></vw:UserControl1>
    </TabItem>
<TabControl>
</Grid>
```

UserControl1.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Label Height="43" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,128,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Content="{Binding Path=UC1Figure, ElementName=uc}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />
    <Button Name="updateSomeFigure" Content="Press Me" Click="updateSomeFigure_Click" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="69,12,66,71" />
</Grid>
```

UserControl1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeFigureProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("UC1Figure", typeof(int), typeof(UserControl1));

    public int UC1Figure
    {
        get { return (int)this.GetValue(SomeFigureProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(SomeFigureProperty, value); }
    }

    private void updateSomeFigure_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UC1Figure = UC1Figure + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `<Label Content="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=vw:UserControl1}}"/>` doesn't work. You don't have any `UserControl1` elements as a parent for `TabItem`, and your `UserControl1` doesn't have a `Header` property.

Comment: Sorry, 'Header' should be SomeText

Comment: No problem. Even after changing that it won't work because your binding `RelativeSource` is wrong. There is no parent element of type `UserControl1` for your `TabItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to data bind a property to the UI of your `UserControl`, you have two options. The first is to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in your code behind. The second is to define `DependencyProperty`s instead of regular CLR properties. You can find out how to do that in the [Dependency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

You might also want to read the [Data Binding Overview‎](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN before you start data `Binding`.