# WPF Binding a Main Window Control from a UserControl View Model

Tags: wpf, user-controls, tabcontrol, wcf-binding, wpf-4.0

So as mentioned in an earlier question I asked [WPF Data Binding From UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20096243/wpf-data-binding-from-usercontrol) I have succesfulyl binded the TabHeader of my Control based off a value inside my UserControls code behind file using DependencyProperty, and acheived a a similar implementation with INotifyPropertyChanged.

However I now need it to work off the value from the UserControls ViewModel. I can succesfully update the UserControl UI using INotifyPropertyChanged but I am unable to bind this value to the TabItem control in the Main Window as it seems to regonise it.

Is this even possibly or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Main Window (TabControl) <---> UserControl <---> ViewModel

MainWindow.xaml

```
   <Grid>
        <TabControl Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,26,0,0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="tab1ItemHeaderStyle" >
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" >
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem}}"/>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=SomeFigureVM, ElementName=uc1}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
            <TabItem Style="{StaticResource tab1ItemHeaderStyle}" Header="[Tab 1]" Name="tabItem1">
                <vw:UserControl1 x:Name="uc1"></vw:UserControl1>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

UserControl1.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Label Height="43" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,128,0,0" Name="textBlock" Content="{Binding SomeFigureVM}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />
    <Button Name="updateSomeFigure" Content="Update.." Click="updateSomeFigure_Click" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="69,12,66,71" />
</Grid>
```

UserControl1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }

    private void updateSomeFigure_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyViewModel viewmodel = this.DataContext as MyViewModel;

        viewmodel.UpdateFigure();
    }
}
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
  public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            this.SomeFigureVM = 23;
        }

        private int _someFigure;


        public int SomeFigureVM
        {
            get 
            {
                return _someFigure ;
            }
            set 
            { 
                _someFigure = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SomeFigureVM");
            }
        }

        public void UpdateFigure()
        {
            SomeFigureVM = SomeFigureVM + 1;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
```

As always, any help is greatly appreciated, I feel like I've been smashing my head against a brick wall on this one!

Comment: [Do not hardcode the DataContext into a UserControl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16488618/302677). It defeats one of the biggest benefits about WPF of having separate UI and data layers. If you're interested, I have a blog article that may help you understand WPF's `DataContext` a bit better: [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SomeFigureVM is a property on your `MyViewModel`, which is the `DataContext` for `UserControl1`. You are trying to access SomeFigureVM prperty on UserControl, which doesn't exist.

Change this line:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=SomeFigureVM, ElementName=uc1}"/>
```

to

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=DataContext.SomeFigureVM, ElementName=uc1}"/>
```

To catch data binding errors like this, run the application in debug mode and watch the output window for any data binding issues. Your original code generates a data binding error like:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'SomeFigureVM' property not found on 'object' ''UserControl1'
>   (Name='uc1')'. BindingExpression:Path=SomeFigureVM;
>   DataItem='UserControl1' (Name='uc1'); target element is 'Label'
>   (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')